# Firefox TypeError: ServiceWorker script encountered an error during installation

Tags: javascript, firefox, service-worker, web-push

I'm developing web push notification on my website. I follow the [Web Push Notifications](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/) of Google and [The Service Worker Cookbook](https://serviceworke.rs/push-payload_demo.html) of Mozilla.

I have tested on the Google Chrome v50+ and everything is working but I will get the error below on Firefox 44, 45, 46, 52, latest Firefox (version 57.0.4 64 bit) when calling `navigator.serviceWorker.register('./push-service-worker.js')` function.

> TypeError: ServiceWorker script at http://localhost:9600/push-service-worker.js for scope http://localhost:9600/ encountered an error during installation.

This is my code:

**Register ServiceWorker in controller.js**

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('push-service-worker.js')
.then((registration) => {
  return registration.pushManager.getSubscription()
    .then((subscription) => {
      if (subscription) {
        return subscription;
      }
      var subscribeOptions = {
        userVisibleOnly: true,
        applicationServerKey: buildApplicationServerKey(),
      };
      return registration.pushManager.subscribe(subscribeOptions);
    });
})
.then((subscription) => {
  sendSubscriptionToServer(subscription);
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('Unable to subscribe to push: ', err);
});
```

**push-service-worker.js**

```
'use strict';

self.addEventListener('push', (event) => {
  var payload = event.data.json();
  var title = payload.title || 'Title';
  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.showNotification(title, {
      body: payload.body,
      icon: './common/images/notification-icon-192x192.png',
      image: payload.image || '',
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
  event.notification.close();
  var urlToOpen = new URL('/', self.location.origin).href;
  event.waitUntil(
    clients.matchAll({
      type: 'window',
      includeUncontrolled: true,
    })
      .then((windowClients) => {
        var matchingClient = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
          var windowClient = windowClients[i];
          if (windowClient.url === urlToOpen) {
            matchingClient = windowClient;
            break;
          }
        }

        if (matchingClient) {
          return matchingClient.focus();
        } else {
          return clients.openWindow(urlToOpen);
        }
      })
  );
});
```

**Directory structure**

```
./root
  ---- manifest.json
  ---- push-service-worker.js
  ---- src
       ---- controller.js
```

Thank for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **wanderview** said at [here](https://github.com/mozilla/serviceworker-cookbook/issues/291#issuecomment-369373962):

> FWIW, you should always use a separate profile for each channel (release/beta/dev-edition/nightly). We're working on making it work like that out-of-the-box, but its not ready yet.

This problem is encountered when I use one profile for multiple Firefox version. To fix this issue go to `about:support` and click `Refresh Firefox`. If it doesn't work, you can go to `about:profiles`, click `Create new profile`, and then `Launch profile in new browser`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was caused by Firefox not being able to access the `serviceworker.js` file.

The server I was hosting it on had a permissions check based on cookies, and in this case Firefox was not sending the cookie as I believe it was considered a cross-site script.

On the server, I made the `serviceworker.js` file accessible publicly, and then Firefox could register the service worker.

It was particularly difficult to notice this, because the Firefox Developer Tools did not show the Forbidden response in the Console, nor did it even show any request for `serviceworker.js` in the Network tab.

Therefore, presumably the `TypeError` is in fact a generic error and should be read as 'something went wrong registering the Service Worker'.

Answer (score 0):

this error can be caused by the service worker file not being reachable or not existing

Answer (score 0):

as per @tbigby Answer, I moved my serviceworker.js file to 'assets' folder and was able to register service worker successfully.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34783167)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox did this to me because Typescript generated an empty `export {};`. I have `type: "module"` in the service worker registration options. I suspect this is a bug in Firefox.